# D3 circular x-axis line graph

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, visualization, radial

Code & result is here: https://jsfiddle.net/nohjose/fdarxu7j/3/#&togetherjs=HpJOmlQkpI

I have coded a d3 (or at least d3 like) radial line graph to show solar panel generation rates over the last four years. I want to have a single line per year (different colour per year) outside the base circle and with a maximum set by a control (which varies the value of the variable 'amplitude'). I have data for every 10mins providing the panels didn't generate 0 Watts but for this graph plan to average the data for each day. I have a php file that returns JSON data in this form
`["2014-01-01 09:00:00","0.018"]["2014-01-01 09:00:00","0.018"]["2014-01-01 09:00:00","0.018"]["2014-01-01 09:00:00","0.018"]...`
I don't see how I'd now plot the data on my graph? 
I know this may not be specific enough for StackOverflow but I'm stuck at the point before where I have a specific technical issue and I'm not sure where else to turn. Kindness appreciated :o)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Solar Generation Visualisation</title>
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <style>
      .xAxis {
        fill: yellow;
        stroke: orange;
        stroke-width: 3px;
      }
      .xBigTick {
        fill: none;
        stroke: red;
        stroke-width: 1px;
      }
      .xSmallTick {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #303030;
        stroke-width: 0.25px;
      }
      .axisText {
        font-family: Lato;
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 8pt;
      }
      .button {
        fill: silver;
        stroke: gray;
        stroke-width: 3px;
      }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Get the data
        var data;
        d3.json("./test.php", function(error, json) {
            if (error) return console.warn(error);
            data = json;
            data.forEach(function(d) {
                d.Timestamp = parseDate(d.Timestamp);
                d.Power = +d.Power;
            });

            // Scale the range of the data
            x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Timestamp; }));
            y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Power; })]);
        });
    </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        var canvasWidth= 1000;
        var canvasHeight= 500;
        var originx = canvasWidth/2;
        var originy = canvasHeight/2;
        var pi = Math.PI;
        var DRratio = pi/180;
        var degPerDay = 360/365;
        var radPerDay = degPerDay*DRratio;
        var bigTick = 100;
        var smallTick = 20;
        var baseRad = canvasHeight/2-bigTick;
        //var baseRad = 200;
        var amplitude = 1; //for magnifying the y axis data
        var textMargin = 25;
        var textMargin180 = 11;
        var angleAdjust = 1.5*DRratio;
        var angleAdjust180 = 5*DRratio;
        var monthAngleAdjust = -18*DRratio;
        var week = 0;

        // Canvas
        var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", canvasWidth)
            .attr("height", canvasHeight);

        // x axis line (radial version)
        var circle = d3.select("svg")
            .append("circle")
            .attr("cx", originx)
            .attr("cy", originy)
            .attr("r", baseRad)
            .attr("class", "xAxis");

        // weekly (big) tick marks
        for (a=0; a<=2*pi; a+=(radPerDay)*7) {
            var line = d3.select("svg")
                .append("line")
                .attr("x1", originx + (baseRad * Math.cos(a)))
                .attr("y1", originy + (baseRad * Math.sin(a)))
                .attr("x2", originx + ((baseRad + bigTick) * Math.cos(a)))
                .attr("y2", originy + ((baseRad + bigTick) * Math.sin(a)))
                .attr("class", "xBigTick");
        };

        // axis labels
        for (a=0; a<=2*pi; a+=(radPerDay)*7) {

            var group = d3.select("svg")
                .append("g")

                //console.log('week-' + week + '   angle:' + a/DRratio + 'degrees'+ '   cos:' + Math.cos(a)+ '   Sin:' + Math.sin(a));

            var text = d3.select("g")
                .append("text")
                .attr("class", "axisText")
                .attr("style", "fill:black")
                .attr("opacity", "1")
                .text(week);

            // adjust the label orientation & tweak the position
            if (a > 0 && (a < (pi/2))){
                text.attr("transform", "translate(" + (originx + (baseRad - textMargin) * Math.cos( -a+angleAdjust )) + "," + (originy - (baseRad - textMargin) * Math.sin( -a+angleAdjust )) + ")rotate(" + (a/DRratio) +")");
            }
            if ((a > (pi/2)) && (a < (3*pi/2))){
                text.attr("transform", "translate(" + (originx + (baseRad - textMargin180) * Math.cos( -a+angleAdjust180 )) + "," + (originy - (baseRad - textMargin180) * Math.sin( -a+angleAdjust180 )) + ")rotate(" + (a/DRratio+180) +")");
            }
            if ((a > (3*pi/2)) && (a < (2*pi))){
                text.attr("transform", "translate(" + (originx + (baseRad - textMargin) * Math.cos( -a+angleAdjust )) + "," + (originy - (baseRad - textMargin) * Math.sin( -a+angleAdjust )) + ")rotate(" + (a/DRratio) +")");
            }
            week=week+1;
        };

                // weekly (big) tick marks
        for (a=0; a<=2*pi; a+=(radPerDay)*7) {
            var line = d3.select("svg")
                .append("line")
                .attr("x1", originx + (baseRad * Math.cos(a)))
                .attr("y1", originy + (baseRad * Math.sin(a)))
                .attr("x2", originx + ((baseRad + bigTick) * Math.cos(a)))
                .attr("y2", originy + ((baseRad + bigTick) * Math.sin(a)))
                .attr("class", "xBigTick");
        };



        // month labels
        var inrad = 100;
        var outrad = baseRad - textMargin;
        var months= [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31];
        var month = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
        var mr = 0;

        // monthly (inner) lead lines
        for (a=0; a<=11; a+=1) {
            var line = d3.select("svg")
                .append("line")
                .attr("x1", originx + (inrad * Math.cos(mr)))
                .attr("y1", originy + (inrad * Math.sin(mr)))
                .attr("x2", originx + (outrad * Math.cos(mr)))
                .attr("y2", originy + (outrad * Math.sin(mr)))
                .attr("class", "xBigTick");
            mr = mr + months[a]*radPerDay;
            //console.log('cumulative day at end of month: ' +  m + '(' + (m * radPerDay) + ')');
        };

        md = 0;
        mr = 0;
        //month text
        for (a=0; a<=11; a+=1) {

            var group = d3.select("svg")
                .append("g")

                //console.log('week-' + week + '   angle:' + a/DRratio + 'degrees'+ '   cos:' + Math.cos(a)+ '   Sin:' + Math.sin(a));

            var text = d3.select("g")
                .append("text")
                .attr("class", "axisText")
                .attr("style", "fill:black")
                .attr("opacity", "1")
                .text(month[a]);

            // adjust the month label orientation & tweak the position
            if (md >= 0 && (md < 90)){
                text.attr("transform", "translate(" + (originx + ((inrad - textMargin) * Math.cos( -mr+monthAngleAdjust ))) + "," + (originy - ((inrad - textMargin) * Math.sin( -mr+monthAngleAdjust ))) + ")rotate(" + (md) +")");
            }
            if ((md > 90) && (md < 270)){
                text.attr("transform", "translate(" + (originx + (inrad ) * Math.cos( -mr+monthAngleAdjust )) + "," + (originy - (inrad) * Math.sin( -mr+monthAngleAdjust )) + ")rotate(" + (md+180) +")");
            }
            if ((md >270) && (md < 360)){
                text.attr("transform", "translate(" + (originx + (inrad - textMargin) * Math.cos( -mr+monthAngleAdjust )) + "," + (originy - (inrad - textMargin) * Math.sin( -mr+monthAngleAdjust )) + ")rotate(" + (md) +")");
            }
            md = md + months[a]*degPerDay;
            mr = mr + months[a]*radPerDay;
            //console.log(md + "deg = " + mr + "rad");
        };

        // daily (small) tick marks
        for (a=0; a<=2*pi; a+=(radPerDay)) {
            var line = d3.select("svg")
                .append("line")
                .attr("x1", originx + (baseRad * Math.cos(a)))
                .attr("y1", originy + (baseRad * Math.sin(a)))
                .attr("x2", originx + ((baseRad + smallTick) * Math.cos(a)))
                .attr("y2", originy + ((baseRad + smallTick) * Math.sin(a)))
                .attr("class", "xSmallTick");
        };

        //control handle (move to adjust amplitude)
        var circle = d3.select("svg")
            .append("circle")
            .attr("cx", originx)
            .attr("cy", originy)
            .attr("r", 10)
            .attr("class", "button");

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```